# How do I simplify this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to simplify this:
$$\left(\dfrac{y^2}{-3x^3}\right)^3$$

I was able to simplify it to: $\dfrac{y^6}{-27x^9}$.

I am not sure if I need to move the negative sign outside of the fraction then, so that it reads negative in total. The negative sign in the denominator is what I am struggling with, how can I remove it?

Comment: Yes, you can write it outside the fraction, or even in the numerator.

Comment: Yes, that comes from a proposition of [fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)).

Comment: @boywholived Overkill :P

Comment: @M.Vinay: If you can show an easier *proof*, I will readily agree to your statement.

Comment: @boywholived Overkill given the OP's level, that's all I meant.

Answer (score 7):

This may help you:

$$-\frac{a}{b} = \frac{-a}{b} = \frac{a}{-b}$$

Considering the above, we can see that

$$ -\frac{y^6}{27x^9} = \frac{-y^6}{27x^9} = \frac{y^6}{-27x^9}$$

Although having the negative sign in the denominator is usually frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the power of the x on the denominator should be a 3 not a 9.
Remember that one of the rules for exponents is:
${(x^m)}^n = x^{mn}$.
That aside, I think the negative signs are usually written on the numerator in final answers.

Comment: Actually, in the first post it was "x^", which I edited to $x^3$ (after seeing the $x^9$ in the next step). Looks like this was lost in the later edits.